# How to read user settings in app.config from a diff app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms .exe with an App.config that has a bunch of User Scoped Settings that are set at runtime and saved. 
I want to be able to use the WinForms app to change and save the settings and then click on button to do some work based on the those settings.
I also want to read the user settings in the same .config file from a sep. console app so I can schedule to work to be done as a scheduled task.
What is the best way to be able to do this?

Update:
I tried the reccommendation of using ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration as described in some of the answers like so.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("F:\\Dir\\App.exe");
```

but when I try to retrieve a User Setting like so.

```
string result = config.AppSettings.Settings["DB"].ToString();
```

I get a Null reference error.

From code in the exe however the following correctly returns the DB name.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.DB
```

Where am I going wrong?

Update 2:

So based on some of the answers below I now can use the following to retrieve the raw XML of the section of the user.config file I am interested in from sep. ConsoleApp.

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"D:\PathHere\user.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
System.Configuration.DefaultSection configSection = (System.Configuration.DefaultSection)config.GetSection("userSettings");
string result = configSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But I am still unable to just pull the value for the specific element I am interested in.

Answer (score 7):

this should do it :

```
var clientSettingsSection = (System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection)(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings/YourApplicationName.Properties.Settings"));
var setting = clientSettingsSection.Settings.Get("yourParamName_DB_");
string yourParamName_DB = ((setting.Value.ValueXml).LastChild).InnerText.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to open the configuration file of another executable.

```
Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeFilePath);
// edit configuration settings
conf.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

See ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting these values per user basis you may need to use the ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel) method instead of the current method you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\MyApp.exe.config";
//i have config in the same directory as my another app         
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var settingsSection = (System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection)config.GetSection("userSettings/MyApp.Properties.Settings");
var setting = settingsSection.Settings.Get("MySetting");
var param = ((setting.Value.ValueXml).LastChild).InnerText.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the path to the config file try:

System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("configPath");

string myValue = config.AppSettings.Settings[ "myValue" ].Value;